# Create triangle of ones in two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

So I want to create array [64][64] of 0 in java and create triangle of ones here. I mean something like:

```
0001000
0010100
0100010
1111111
```

So I created class point:

```
public class Point {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

And I'm creating in main new points objects in that way:

```
int amountOfPowers = 6;
Point a = new Point((int) (Math.pow(2, amountOfPowers))/2, 0);
     Point b = new Point((int) Math.pow(2, amountOfPowers), (int) (Math.pow(2, amountOfPowers) * Math.sqrt(3.0) / 2));
     Point c = new Point(0, (int) (Math.pow(2, amountOfPowers) * Math.sqrt(3.0) / 2));
```

So A is `(0, 64)`, B is `(64, 64)` and C is `(32, 55)`. Somebody has any idea how can I write all positions in array from 0,64 to 64,64 as 1? (something like `[0][64] = 1, [1][64] = 1, ..., [64][64] = 1`). 
And also how can I create lines of ones from (0,64) to (32, 55) and from (32, 55) to (64, 64). Somebody have any idea how can I do this?

@edit

I tried to use it:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm

Here is my method:

```
static void drawLine(Point from, Point to) {
        // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm
        int dx = to.x - from.x;
        int dy = to.y - from.y;

        for (int x = from.x; x < to.x; x++) {
            int y = from.y + dx * (x - from.x) / dy;
            System.out.println("X: " + x + " Y: " + y);
            canvas[x][y] = 1;
        }
    }
```

I wrote this in main:

```
drawLine(a, b);
drawLine(b, c);
drawLine(c, a);
```

And here is my result :/ It's something wrong.

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Anybody have idea how can I solve my problem? :/

Comment: Did you hear about `for` loop in java?

Comment: Yes, I heard. But how your comment have to help me?......

Comment: We are not here to do your homework!

Answer (score 0):

If you will think about your arrays as a screen and about 1's as dark pixels and zeroes as white pixels than you have task of drawing a line on screen. In reality it is exactly the task that being actively performed in video card.

Algorithm is expressed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm

NB: in algorithm they use int's and due rounding issues you might be will have better results if you will swap coords and will iterate using y instead of x.

Comment: I tried to use it but it doesn't work :/ Or I don't have idea how to use it.

Comment: I found other algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm I wil check it tomorrow :P Now I go to sleep, thanks for all help :)

Comment: I think 2nd one (Bresenham) will work OK. Good luck!